# I cannot access the file posted using FormData in Postman, in my Web API. HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["document"] returning NULL

Tags: asp.net-web-api, file-upload, postman

I'm trying to post a simple file into my C# WEB API. Here is how it look in Postman:

[image: Postman Screenshot]

[image: Second Postman Screenshot]

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798148/how-to-read-formdata-into-webapi) make it look easy to access the file. It seems that I only need the instruction:

```
var fileToUpload = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["document"];
```

However when I hit the endpoint and I debug, fileToUpload is coming null.

What's wrong??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, even if it supposed to work with code `HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["document"];` following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798148/how-to-read-formdata-into-webapi), it didn't work for me. What actually worked, is using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["document"];`